# Can a PHP script detect if a socket has been closed?

Tags: php, sockets, scripting, connection, webserver

How can a PHP script detect if a socket has been [closed](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-close.php) by the remote party?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [socket_read()](http://php.net/socket_read):

```
socket_read() returns the data as a string on success, or FALSE on error 
(including if the remote host has closed the connection). The error code can 
be retrieved with socket_last_error(). This code may be passed to 
socket_strerror() to get a textual representation of the error.
```

This is the fairly standard approach to detecting if a socket is closed in most languages. I don't believe PHP offers a direct event-style notification (except perhaps something in PEAR).

Comment: @tntu: This is incorrect. `""` is what is returned if there is no data (including non-blocking mode). This is separate and different to `false`.

Comment: Well in blocking mode wouldn't it block until it receives something instead of JUST CHECKING if the connection is closed or not?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but maybe valuable note.
If you call `socket_close($socket);` in multiple places and want to check wether you already closed the socket before or not, you can do it by using following comparison:

```
    if (get_resource_type($socket) === 'Unknown') {
        exit;
    }
```

I found it by dumping socket before and after closing `var_dump($socket);`

- before closing `resource(5) of type (Socket)`
- after closing `resource(5) of type (Unknown)`

But it wont tell you wether socket is closed by other side or not. Basicly when connection is established there are always two sockets - one for each side. So `get_resource_type` will only check your own resource, not the other side.

Answer (score 0):

[`fread($socket)`](http://php.net/fread) returns empty string, instantly, without waiting for the socket to timeout.

(No, this is not a real answer, but this is the hackish solution I have in place in my code ATM. This behaviour might also be windows-specific.)

Comment: This is standard behaviour in most languages/platforms, not just PHP/Windows.

Comment: What gets returned if I call `fread($socket)` when the connection is open?